# Can I use content translated by Google Translate for SEO purposes after proofreading and curating it?

Tags: seo, translation, google-translate

I have a Greek website which I am interested on translating to English. I was never keen of the idea of google translating the content. I want high quality content on both languages and additionally I don't want translating through Google Translate to hurt my site's SEO.

However recently I have tried playing around with my content translation through Google Translate and to my surprise it was pretty much accurate.

So my question is. Is it a good move to translate my content with Google Translate and **after** proofreading and curation of the translation to upload the newly translated content?

Comment: I agree with @Evgeniy although I find Google Translate to be a hit and miss affair. The French phrase *Sonnez les matines* is translated as *Ring the mornings* by https://dictionary.cambridge.org/translate/ (correct). By Google Translate it is translated to *Ring the matins* because it doesn't understand the phrase *les matines*. If you are doing a lot of translation on a regular basis, finding a good translation api will cut your editing time down as it will not need as much editing, which sometimes can lead to more time finding out the correct translation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It makes no difference, how you translate your content. Main keywords are always: proofreading and curation. If these procedures give you the go - then everything is OK.

Google translate or Bing or Promt or a million other translation services - really no difference. They all do their job - more or less good, depending on complexity of the content and their word pool. Proofread it after - and you are on the secure side.

Comment: Google has long warned not to use machine translation without proofreading because it is poor user experience and Google would penalize sites for doing so.   I agree that with proofreading, it should be fine though.